# SwiftUI: Custom font with support for bold and italics

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, swiftui

I want to create a custom font for use in my SwiftUI app. I've created a `Font` extension:

```
static var acBody1: Font {
    return .custom("SuisseIntl", size: 17, relativeTo: .body)
}
static var acBody1Semibold: Font {
    return .custom("SuisseIntl-SemiBold", size: 17, relativeTo: .body)
}
```

But instead of referencing a separate font for semibold, I'd rather do something similar to this...

```
Font.acBody1.semibold()
```

...similar to the way native fonts are used. I have something set up like this in UIKit. I reference the size of the font being used, and then return a semibold font of that size. But from what I can tell, you can't get the `pointSize` of a SwiftUI font once it's been created. And so I'm unsure how to do the `semibold` modifier chaining.

Is this possible?

Comment: just set its weight instead

Comment: But then the user would need to know the exact weight to use for "semibold".

Comment: `.fontWeight(.medium)`

Comment: Actually, doing `Font.acBody1.weight(.semibold)` does work... I was just hoping for something a little more succinct.

Comment: Does this your answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67700447/14733292

Answer (score 1):

Can this help?

```
extension Font {
    
    static var acBody1: Font {
        return .custom("SuisseIntl", size: 17, relativeTo: .body)
    }
    public func semibold() -> Font {
        switch self {
        case .acBody1:
            return .custom("SuisseIntl-SemiBold", size: 17, relativeTo: .body)
        default:
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

**Suggestion:**
Depending on the use case, you can change the `default` case to return `self.weight(.semibold)` so that the `semibold()` function always return a `semi-bolded` font.

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Thanks so much!